# Using arrayformula to add suffix, but would like to skip empty cells

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using an arrayformula to add .png suffix to the text in column A. Right now it looks like this:

```
=arrayformula(A:A &".png" )
```

Since I want this to be a part of a macro, I won't manually be able to choose the exact range.
So how do I limit the formula, to only add the suffix, if the cells in column A had any text in it, to begin with? Right now I end up with a lot of cells where it just says ".png" because the cell was empty.

I have tried playing around with `=if(istext(A:A)` but I couldn't figure out how to construct the statement. And maybe it is not the way to go?

[image: arrayformula to add suffix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A))&".png")
```

[image]

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="",,A:A&".png")
```

or regex:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "(.+)", "$1.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A:A), A:A&".png",))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below code

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A&".png")
```

should do the thing.